# Combine files using Pillow and Python

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

1. I need to run a python script inside a folder.
2. the script count    files    ( image ) number create an image for
   every 64 images.
   example: if the    folder containing 640 images, I will get 10
   images as a combination    of 64 images/outputimage

just, before adding  "for" instruction, I can get a result, but manually and only with the same image ( a duplication of image ).

any idea?

so I proceed as follows:

```
import os
import os.path

from PIL import Image

list = os.listdir(".")  # current directory 
number_files = len(list)
print (number_files)

for x in range(0, number_files):

    # files = ['x.png']  

        # opens an image: here I can't find how 
    im = Image.open("1.png") # here I tried to 

# creates a new empty image, RGB mode, and size 800 by 800.
new_im = Image.new('RGB', (800, 800))

# Here I resize my opened image, so it is no bigger than 100,100
im.thumbnail((100, 100))
# Iterate through a 8 by 8 grid with 100 spacing, to place my image
for i in xrange(0, 800, 100):
    for j in xrange(0, 800, 100):
        # paste the image at location i,j:
        new_im.paste(im, (i, j))
        new_im.save(os.path.expanduser('outputimage.png'))
```

update :

```
import os
import os.path

from PIL import Image


def drange(start, stop, step):
    while start < stop:
        yield start
        start += step


list = os.listdir(".")  # directory path
number_files = len(list)
print (number_files)

new_im = Image.new('RGB', (800, 800))

for x in drange(0, number_files, 64):

    im = Image.open(list[x])
    im.thumbnail((100, 100))

    for i in xrange(0, 800, 100):
        for j in xrange(0, 800, 100):

            new_im.paste(im, (i, j))

new_im.save(os.path.expanduser('out.png'))
```

other update based on Sven solution :

```
import os.path

from PIL import Image

fileList = [] where_to_look = "png/" 
  for f in os.listdir(where_to_look):
        if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(where_to_look, f)):
            fileList.append(f)
             print (len(fileList))


target_img = None n_targets = 0 collage_saved = False

for n in range(len(fileList)):
    img = Image.open(fileList[n])
    img.thumbnail((100, 100))

    if n % 64 == 0:
        # create an empty image for a collage
        target_img = Image.new("RGB", (800, 800))
        n_targets += 1
        collage_saved = False

    # paste the image at the correct position
    i = int(n / 8)
    j = n % 8
    target_img.paste(img, (100*i, 100*j))

    if (n + 1) % 64 == 0 and target_img is not None:
        # save a finished 8x8 collage
        target_img.save("{0:04}.png".format(n_targets))
        collage_saved = True

# save the last collage if not collage_saved:
    target_img.save("{0:04}.png".format(n_targets))
```

Comment: Some hints: 1. You always open the same image ("1.png"). To open each image, use Image.open(list[x]) 2. In each iteration of the for-loop, you are discarding your previously opened image and replacing it by a new instance. Therefore `im` in the second to last line always has the same value. Move this part into the first for-loop. 3. this will only work for the first 64 images, as you run the two for-loops at the end only once

Comment: @SvenFestersen , thks for your suggestion 
I updated the code, could you check please ?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your update, I quickly sketched a solution. Please beware that I did not test it:

```
import os
from PIL import Image

image_dir = os.path.abspath("png")
# list all files in directory
files = os.listdir(image_dir)
# get all PNGs
png_files = filter(lambda x: x.endswith(".png"), files)
# make file paths absolute
image_files = map(lambda x: os.sep.join([image_dir, x]), png_files)

n_files = len(image_files)

target_img = None
n_targets = 0
collage_saved = False
for n in range(n_files):
    img = Image.open(image_files[n])
    img.thumbnail((100, 100))

    if n % 64 == 0:
        # create an empty image for a collage
        target_img = Image.new("RGB", (800, 800))
        n_targets += 1
        collage_saved = False

    # paste the image at the correct position
    i = int(n / 8)
    j = n % 8
    target_img.paste(img, (100*i, 100*j))

    if (n + 1) % 64 == 0 and target_img is not None:
        # save a finished 8x8 collage
        target_img.save("{0:04}.png".format(n_targets))
        collage_saved = True

# save the last collage
if not collage_saved:
    target_img.save("{0:04}.png".format(n_targets))
```

This will iterate over all your images and assemble them in a 8x8 grid (I call it collage in the script). Whenever the grid is filled, the collage is saved as a file with the naming pattern 0001.png, 0002.png and so on.

Note that there are some points to improve:

1. `os.listdir(".")` will give you all files in the directory, not only images. You would have to filter the output for image files.
2. This only works in the current working directory.
3. The output is also saved to the current working directory.

UPDATE: filter PNGs and use absolute paths

Comment: thanks 
I tried your solution but doesn't work since in the same folder there is the python script.
So I fixed the issue of reading from another folder
I put all png file in a folder named "png"
next, I run the script outside this folder, but an issue appeared indicated that "28.png" doesn't exist??
please check my update

Comment: It's much easier than that! Have a look at my updated answer.

Comment: thanks a lot, it work, but only for the first output image.
I got 10 images, the first one contain 8x8 images, the others are empty ( black ).
also, since my png files are a sequence from 0.png to 640.png, it seems your solution take an image from the list without sequenced way, I will try to fix that.